# Unable to login to dedicated server over remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, password, remote, desktop

I have a dedicated server which I rented on online.net. It's a Windows Server 2012. I changed the administrator password from within the server, but now I can't login to my server over remote desktop. I can rescue the server with Ubuntu, Windows PE and FreeBSD. The server has the iDRAC system, too.

How can I change the password?

Answer (score 1):

You can mount an ISO as a cd drive using idrac, do that and boot a from a password recovery tool such as pogostick https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/ .